# Display Json data in mobile app

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js, devextreme

I really hope and pray you can help me, as I have had not much luck trying to figure things out on my own.

I am trying to create an app using Devextreme

My code looks like the following -
db.js

```
(function () {
   var dbImpl = {
       url: 'http://localhost/service/GetCustomers';,
       _sendRequest: function (type, params) {
           var deferred = new $.Deferred();
           var requestSettings = {
               url: $.trim(dbImpl.url),
               type: type,
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (data) {
                   deferred.resolve(data);
               },
               error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   deferred.reject();
               }
           };
           if (params) {
               if (type == 'DELETE') {
                   if (requestSettings.url[requestSettings.url.lebgth - 1] != '/')
                       requestSettings.url += '/';
                   requestSettings.url += params.toString();
               }
               else
                   requestSettings.data = params;
           }
           $.ajax(requestSettings);
           return deferred;
       },
       load: function (loadOptions) {
           var params = {
               filterOptions: JSON.stringify(loadOptions.filter),   //Getting filter options
               sortOptions: loadOptions.sort ? JSON.stringify(loadOptions.sort) : null,  //Getting sort options

               //skip and take are used for paging
               skip: loadOptions.skip, //A number of records that should be skipped
               take: loadOptions.take //A number of records that should be taken
           };
           return dbImpl._sendRequest('GET', params);
       },
       totalCount: function (loadOptions) {
           var params = {
               filterOptions: JSON.stringify(loadOptions.filter)   //Getting filter options
           };
           var def = $.Deferred();
           dbImpl._sendRequest('GET', params).done(function (result) {
               def.resolve(result.length);
           })
           .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               def.reject();
           });
           return def.promise();
       },
       insert: function (values) {
           return dbImpl._sendRequest('POST', values);
       },
       update: function (key, values) {
           var params = $.extend({}, values);
           params[dbImpl.key] = key;
           return dbImpl._sendRequest('PUT', params);
       },
       remove: function (key) {
           return dbImpl._sendRequest('DELETE', key);
       }
   };
   UmbrellaMobile.db = new DevExpress.data.CustomStore(dbImpl);
})();
```

Customer.js :

```
UmbrellaMobile.Customer = function (params) {

   var viewModel = {
       gridSettings: {
           dataSource: UmbrellaMobile.db,
           columns: [
               {
                   dataField: 'Code',
                   allowEditing: false

               },
               {
                   dataField: 'Name'
               }
           ],
           paging: {
               enabled: true,
               pageSize: 3
           },
           editing: {
               editEnabled: true,
               insertEnabled: true,
               removeEnabled: true
           },
           filterRow: {
               visible: true
           },
           groupPanel: {
               visible: true
           },
           remoteOperations: {
               filtering: true,
               paging: true,
               sorting: true
           }
       }
   };

   return viewModel;
};
```

Customer.dxView:

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'Customer', title: 'Customer' } " >
   <div  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >

 <div data-bind="dxDataGrid: gridSettings"></div>

       </div>
</div>
```

My service looks like :

Interface - :

```
 <OperationContract()> _
      <WebInvoke(Method:="GET", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="GetCustomers")> _
   Function GetCustomers() As Customers
```

service.vb :

```
   Function GetCustomers() As Customers Implements IUmbrellaMobileService.GetCustomers

       Try
           Dim Cust As New Customers

....

Return Cust
```

the service returns `{"Code":"001","Name":"rainbow"}`

My app doesn't show any of my json data, and I do not know how to connect the two. After lots of research I finally managed to get my service sorted out, now I need to display the data from the service inside my app. I have tried millions of different options and I am not coming right with any of the routes I have taken.

Basically, I just need to know how to connect jquery with my data that was returned from my service. Can anyone help?

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: OK, progress... the problem is in the db.js file with this line :          $.ajax(requestSettings);
            return deferred; what could be the problem?

Comment: Yeah, remove the extra semicolon after url field value. here, right before comma: `url: 'http://localhost/service/GetCustomers';,`